# the play button not working for the external video

Tags: javascript, html

When I click on the play/pause button nothing seems to happen, after clicking on the video  I want to play, the vs code is not finding me any error nor the dev console.

I don't know what the issue is with the play/pause button.
Also, there is some issue with the third video, when I click on the third video it gives the following error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded :5500/favicon.ico:1 with a status of 404 (Not Found)

```js
window.onload = init;

function init() {
  var frame1 = document.querySelector('#video1');

  frame1.innerHTML += ' <br> <button id="play">play </button> <button id="pause">pause</button> <button id="volume-up">volume up</button> <button id="volume down">volume-down</button> <button id="mute">mute</button>  ';
}


//to play another video
var click = document.querySelectorAll('#videos > div');

click.forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('click', nextPlaylist);

    function nextPlaylist(evt) {
      var save = elem.querySelector('.video').currentSrc;
      var save1 = elem.querySelector('.video');

      elem.innerHTML = `<video class="video" > <source src="${save}"> </video>  <br> <button id="play">play </button> <button id="pause">pause</button> <button id="volume-up">volume up</button> <button id="volume down">volume-down</button> <button id="mute">mute</button>  `;

      var play = document.querySelector('#play');

      play.addEventListener('click', playVid);

      var pause = document.querySelector('#pause');

      pause.addEventListener('click', pauseVid);

      function playVid() {
        save1.play();
      }

      function pauseVid() {
        save1.pause();
      }
    }
  }

);
```

```html
<body>
  <header class="head">
    VIDEO PLAYER
  </header>
  <div id="videos">
    <div id="video1">
      <video class="video" controls>
        <source src="https://www.videvo.net/videvo_files/converted/2018_04/preview/180301_06_A_CityRoam_03.mp420186.webm">
    </video>
    </div>
    <div id="video2">
      <video class="video" controls>
        <source src= "https://www.videvo.net/videvo_files/converted/2016_01/preview/Forest_15_2_Videvo.mov92730.webm">
      </video>
    </div>
    <div id="video3">
      <video class="video" controls>
        <source src="https://www.videvo.net/videvo_files/converted/2016_09/preview/160820_125_NYC_OutOfFocusCarLights5_1080p.mp444096.webm">
      </video>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="video.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: `when I click on the third video it gives some error` - what exactly error did you get?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded :5500/favicon.ico:1  with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @user:6277104, Failed to load resource: the server responded  :5500/favicon.ico:1 with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with the code.

1. You declare the video element but then override it.

```js
var save1= elem.querySelector('.video');
```

but then, you remove that element and render a different one

```js
elem.innerHTML = `<video class="video" >...
```

So you need to retrieve it again (or just move `var save1= elem.querySelector('.video');` after the line above.

2. When the user clicks on the buttons the parent's listener (`elem.addEventListener('click', nextPlaylist);` also get fired, so it re-render the videos.

To avoid that, use [`stopPropagation`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_stoppropagation.asp#:~:text=The%20stopPropagation()%20method%20prevents,capturing%20down%20to%20child%20elements.) to prevent from the event from propagate to the parent

3. You have multiple `id` attribute with the same value (when the user clicks on more than one video) so `document.querySelector` catch the first one (which wasn't work too because the reasons above).

Replace the `id`s to `class`es and use `elem.querySelector` instead of `document.querySelector` to make sure it will find the buttons in a specific div.

```js
//to play another video
var click = document.querySelectorAll('#videos > div');

click.forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', nextPlaylist);
});

function nextPlaylist(evt) {
  const elem = evt.currentTarget;
  var save = elem.querySelector('.video').currentSrc;

  elem.innerHTML = `<video class="video" > <source src="${save}"> </video>  <br> <button class="play">play </button> <button class="pause">pause</button> <button id="volume-up">volume up</button> <button id="volume down">volume-down</button> <button id="mute">mute</button>  `;
  var save1 = elem.querySelector('.video');

  var play = elem.querySelector('.play');

  play.addEventListener('click', playVid);

  var pause = elem.querySelector('.pause');

  pause.addEventListener('click', pauseVid);

  function playVid(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    save1.play();
  }

  function pauseVid(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    save1.pause();
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="head">
  VIDEO PLAYER
</header>
<div id="videos">
  <div id="video1">
    <video class="video" controls>
      <source src="https://www.videvo.net/videvo_files/converted/2018_04/preview/180301_06_A_CityRoam_03.mp420186.webm">
    </video>
  </div>
  <div id="video2">
    <video class="video" controls>
      <source src= "https://www.videvo.net/videvo_files/converted/2016_01/preview/Forest_15_2_Videvo.mov92730.webm">
    </video>
  </div>
  <div id="video3">
    <video class="video" controls>
      <source src="https://www.videvo.net/videvo_files/converted/2016_09/preview/160820_125_NYC_OutOfFocusCarLights5_1080p.mp444096.webm">
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

By the way, you can move the function out. It's a shame to create new function for each element instead of only one.

https://jsbin.com/koritub/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @user:863110, thanks for the help , It would have been very difficult for me to figure these things out as a beginner, hope you keep helping others.